# Different colors in Altair Ridgeline plot

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite, ridgeline-plot

It's an extension to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65837215/altair-ridgeline-doesnt-create-a-plot-with-nominal-groups) about the Altair Ridgeline plot.

I have a plot which created like this:

```
import pandas as np
import numpy as np

source = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('ab'))
source['a'] = np.random.randint(0,17,size=500)
source['color'] = source['a'].apply(lambda x: 'blue' if x < 10 else 'red'] 
source['a'] = source['a'].astype('str')
source['b'] = np.random.randint(1000,5000,size=500).astype('float')


import altair as alt

step = 20
overlap = 1

alt.Chart(source, height=step).transform_joinaggregate(
    mean_temp='mean(b)', groupby=['a']
).transform_bin(
    ['bin_max', 'bin_min'], 'b'
).transform_aggregate(
    value='count()', groupby=['a', 'b', 'bin_min', 'bin_max']
).transform_impute(
    impute='value', groupby=['a', 'b'], key='bin_min', value=0
).mark_area(
    interpolate='monotone',
    fillOpacity=0.8,
    stroke='lightgray',
    strokeWidth=0.5
).encode(
    alt.X('bin_min:Q', bin='binned', title=''),
    alt.Y(
        'value:Q',
        scale=alt.Scale(range=[step, -step * overlap]),
        axis=None
    ),
    alt.Fill(
        'b:Q',
        legend=None,
    )
).facet(
    row=alt.Row(
        'a:N',
        title=None,
        header=alt.Header(labelAngle=0, labelAlign='right')
    )
).properties(
    title='',
    bounds='flush'
).configure_facet(
    spacing=0
).configure_view(
    stroke=None
).configure_title(
    anchor='end'
)
```

My question is how to make rows of the plot different colors ('blue' or 'red' depending on 'color' column in dataframe)? I tried to configure it using `alt.Scale(domain='color:N')` in `alt.Fill()`, `color='color:N'` param in `encode()` but it wouldn't work. Facet header labels should be colored as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the fill or color encoding to the `"color"` column with a [raw scale](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html#raw-color-values).

That said, you have already set the color encoding based on the `"b"` column, so you need to encode this information differently; for example, you could use Opacity instead.

Here is an example of putting these together:

```python
import pandas as np
import numpy as np

source = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('ab'))
source['a'] = np.random.randint(0,17,size=500)
source['color'] = source['a'].apply(lambda x: 'blue' if x < 10 else 'red')
source['a'] = source['a'].astype('str')
source['b'] = np.random.randint(1000,5000,size=500).astype('float')


import altair as alt

step = 20
overlap = 1

alt.Chart(source, height=step).transform_joinaggregate(
    mean_temp='mean(b)', groupby=['a']
).transform_bin(
    ['bin_max', 'bin_min'], 'b'
).transform_aggregate(
    value='count()', groupby=['a', 'b', 'bin_min', 'bin_max', 'color']
).transform_impute(
    impute='value', groupby=['a', 'b', 'color'], key='bin_min', value=0
).mark_area(
    interpolate='monotone',
    fillOpacity=0.8,
    stroke='lightgray',
    strokeWidth=0.5
).encode(
    alt.X('bin_min:Q', bin='binned', title=''),
    alt.Y(
        'value:Q',
        scale=alt.Scale(range=[step, -step * overlap]),
        axis=None
    ),
    alt.Fill('color:N', scale=None),
    alt.Opacity(
        'b:Q',
        legend=None,
    )
).facet(
    row=alt.Row(
        'a:N',
        title=None,
        header=alt.Header(labelAngle=0, labelAlign='right')
    )
).properties(
    title='',
    bounds='flush'
).configure_facet(
    spacing=0
).configure_view(
    stroke=None
).configure_title(
    anchor='end'
)
```

[image]

Comment: You are saving me again. Thanks!